# How to avoid polygon distortion when zooming?

Tags: echarts

Here is a full [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/k9aof5pd/25/)

I use a custom series and draw a polygon:

```
data = [
  [80.9251933067, 207.9047427038],
  [52.8853803102, 337.7443022089],
  [25.9926385814, 120.3586150136]
];
```

I use [echarts.graphi.clipPointsByRect()](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#echarts.graphic.clipPointsByRect) (like in this [echarts-example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=custom-cartesian-polygon)) to make sure, the polygon is not drawn outside of the grid.

```
echarts.graphic.clipPointsByRect(points, {
        x: params.coordSys.x,
        y: params.coordSys.y,
        width: params.coordSys.width,
        height: params.coordSys.height
      })
```

Initially the polygon is drawn correctly, like this:
[image]

But when I zoom in, the polygon is distorted: e.g. you can click the `zoom part` buttom below the chart to zoom from 40 to 60 - in this case I'd expect to see the part of the shape (like highlighted in yellow in the image above) - but instead I see this distorted image:
[image]

Maybe this function is not meant for this use-case, or is this a bug?
Is there another function for this use-case or does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: It appears to be working fine, you just don't like how it looks. If you notice the points remain exactly where they should, when you "zoom" you are only zooming on the x-axis which means those coordinates are appearing further apart from one another since the scale is changing. It isn't your polygon that is truly distorting, it is your zooming is behaving in an undesirable way, make sure you're also zooming on y-axis.

Comment: I don't think the points remain where they should. If you look at the zoomed image, it seems, that the first point is at x=40 - but in fact, it should be at X=25, right?

Comment: don't zoom in as far, it remains in the same x coordinate until it hits the edge, then it starts to remain on the edge. My guess even in this case is that it really never is moving, just displaying to the edge and cant display further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Version 4.4.x contains a new `clip` feature. This makes it easy to avoid the distortion:

- in the render function we don't need to clip our shapes: i.e. no need to call `clipPointsByRect()`
- instead we just activate `clip` on the custom series:

New series definition with `clip: 'true'`:

```
series: [{
    type: 'custom',
    clip: 'true',
    renderItem: renderItem,
    data: data
  }]
```

Here is an updated [jsfiddle expample](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/r2zb98uo/)

**Original Version**

it seems that the function is really not working as expected - see [echarts-source code comment](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/2b86ddd81780198a5d1a126e29a196558b8c4411/src/util/graphic.js#L1197):

```
export function clipPointsByRect(points, rect) {
    // FIXME: this way migth be incorrect when grpahic clipped by a corner.
    // and when element have border.
```

I've created an issue [#10222](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/10222) for the e-charts project

A workaround for now is to use a custom clipping function
e.g. [lineclip](https://github.com/mapbox/lineclip) supports the [Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm) for polygon clipping

Here is the updated [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/k9aof5pd/34/) that shows the correct result when you zoom in:
[image]